# How can I wipe my SD card on an unresponsive Nexus 4?

Tags: sd-card, nexus-4

About two years ago, I dropped my Nexus 4 and shattered the screen. It no longer registered touches and is unusable. I'm finally getting around to recycling all of my busted electronics, and I realized that this device still has all of my personal data on it, and I'm pretty sure it wasn't encrypted. I'd like to factory reset my device, but I can't actually interact with the phone's OS to do that. Removing the SD card would also probably be an acceptable option as a last resort.

If it matters, I bought it unlocked and used T-Mobile's prepaid service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a factory reset with just using the physical buttons.

**Step 1:** Boot into recovery mode.

**Step 2:** Perform a reset from your recovery.

These steps don't require screen to sense touches. If your screen is completely gone so it shows nothing [here's a video of it](https://youtu.be/PaSP38BNk4U?t=170) so you can follow from there.